# Read OS X partition from Windows 7

Tags: windows, macos, mac, filesystems, hfs

I have installed Windows 7 onto my Macbook using Boot Camp, but i find the whole experience very quiet seeing I cannot access my music that resides on the OS X partition. Is there software out there that allows me to read (and maybe write) OS X file systems?

Although free is always proffered, as long as it isn't expensive, I am not against forking out a couple bucks to buy quality software.

It would be very good if the partition would show up the same as any other partition so I can navigate it using Explorer or any other software.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/) is what you're after. It's $50 for a CD or Download if that's within your budget, I can guarantee it's quality software.

For a free alternative as already mentioned, HFSExplorer works well, but it will not integrate like any other disk as you prefer.

If you are running Windows 7 under Boot Camp however, [OS X 10.6 will include HFS drivers](http://www.ditii.com/2009/05/09/apple-includes-hfs-windows-drivers-to-snow-leopards-boot-camp/) with Boot Camp to read OS X partitions from Windows.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for HFSExplorer: http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/

Comment: worth noting that HFSExplorer is read-only for HFS partitions.

Answer (score 5):

The version of Boot Camp that comes with Snow Leopard will contain HFS+ drivers for Windows. Rather than buy additional utilities, you might prefer to wait for the upgrade.

*"Boot Camp now includes HFS+ read support that enables you to access the files on your Mac OS X partition from Windows. It’s read-only to prevent PC viruses from affecting Mac OS X, but you can easily save your work to your Windows partition and access it later from Mac OS X."*

From http://www.apple.com/macosx/refinements/enhancements-refinements.html

Answer (score 2):

[HFS+ for Windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/) from Paragon is a read/**write** driver. It's only $19.99, so it may a good alternative to a more expensive MacDrive. I used their NTFS driver for Mac, and it worked fine.