# How to View Mac Volume inside Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read and write Mac drives on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/138653/how-to-read-and-write-mac-drives-on-windows)

Anybody has any experience with accessing (reading) Mac Volume files from Windows?
Any suggestions or advise is welcome :)

Update: would prefer freeware if there is any

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read and write Mac drives on Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/138653/how-to-read-and-write-mac-drives-on-windows) and [Read OS X partition from Windows 7
](http://superuser.com/questions/7868/read-os-x-partition-from-windows-7)

Comment: right it does look like its duplicated thanks for point it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [MacDrive by MediaFour](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/) to access my Mac HD from my Windows 7 laptop. Works well, but latest versions are not free. Basically allows you to mount HFS+ disks in Windows - read and write, no size limits.